# I want to integrate mxgraph with angular 4

Tags: angular, mxgraph

I took some idea from this https://github.com/sibaspage/mxgraph-with-angular2.git. I can run this code on my machine but not completely Export and import are not working. What I want to do to export the diagram in xml and import diagram xml as well.

Comment: Welcome to SO. What error/issue do you face while importing/exporting? Show the code snippet that you tried so far. 

Have a read at this [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: goes on mxdisabled-       if (this.labels)
 {
  var col2 = document.createElement('td');
  col2.className = 'mxPopupMenuItem' +
   ((enabled != null && !enabled) ? ' mxDisabled' : '');
  
  mxUtils.write(col2, title);
  col2.align = 'left';
  tr.appendChild(col2);
 
  var col3 = document.createElement('td');
  col3.className = 'mxPopupMenuItem' +
   ((enabled != null && !enabled) ? ' mxDisabled' : '');
  col3.style.paddingRight = '6px';
  col3.style.textAlign = 'right';
  
  tr.appendChild(col3);
  
  if (parent.div == null)
  {
   this.createSubmenu(parent);
  }
 }

Comment: I am sorry for inconvenience. Actually export in labels not working. Can you please help me out in exporting and importing xml in mxgraph

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this code you are using is based on the graph editor example from mxgraph (  https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/javascript/examples/grapheditor/www/index.html ).Then Go to `EditorUi.js` file in the function `EditorUi.prototype.save` and use this code

```
    if (this.editor.graph.isEditing())
    {
        this.editor.graph.stopEditing();
    }

    var xml = mxUtils.getXml(this.editor.getGraphXml());
    var xml = mxUtils.getXml(this.editor.getGraphXml()); 

    uriContent = "data:Application/octet-stream,"+ encodeURIComponent(xml); 
    newWindow = window.open(uriContent, 'neuesDokument');
```

After that, you can use CTRL + S on the diagram editor or press Save on the menu options and this should work just fine.

Comment: Can you help me in clone multiple node while dragging single node. e.g, If I clicked Circle in sidebar shapes then Circle and double circle cloned in grid section. Is it possible with the same code.

Comment: Glad i can help :) , please accept this answer (check button) so that more people can be helped. 
Sorry, but I do not understand much of nods, I have not worked with this part yet. I hope you find your answer, good luck

Comment: Thank you for your response. If you will get answer to my question please help me!

Comment: You may find your answer here: https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/docs/js-api/files/model/mxCell-js.html on the api documentation . The clone function should help you with that

Comment: Hey! I am new in mxgraph. Can you please help me in how to make a node having only outgoing edges not incoming edges to that node? Thanks in advance!!!!